# Radio Buttons not sending correct value with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a group of radiobuttons listing all the available grades in a school. The onchange event fires an Ajax request that returns all available subjects for that particular grade and displays them in a listbox. Unfortunately it always returns the value of the first radio button in the group. Everything else still works except for the wrong radio button value being passed.

The process works perfectly if I use another listbox instead of the radio buttons.

I feel that I am missing the bleeding obvious, but I can't see what.  Any suggestions gratefully received.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
function ajaxFunction(sender){    
    var ajaxRequest;  
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById(sender + "div");
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    // Now get the value from user and pass it to the server script.
    var grade = document.getElementById(sender).value;  //works
    var queryString = "?grade=" + grade + "&subject=" + sender;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "process_ajax_7.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
    <form action="process.php" method="get" name="myform">
        <label><input type="radio" id = "subject1" name="subject1" onclick=ajaxFunction('subject1'); value="09">Grade 9</label>
        <label><input type="radio" id = "subject1" name="subject1" onclick=ajaxFunction('subject1'); value="10">Grade 10</label>
        <label><input type="radio" id = "subject1" name="subject1" onclick=ajaxFunction('subject1'); value="11">Grade 11</label>
        <label><input type="radio" id = "subject1" name="subject1" onclick=ajaxFunction('subject1'); value="12">Grade 12</label>
        <br><br>
        <select id="subject2" name="subject2" onchange=ajaxFunction('subject2');>
            <option> </option>
            <option value="09"> Year 9 </option>
            <option value="10"> Year 10 </option>
            <option value="11"> Year 11 </option>
            <option value="12"> Year 12 </option>
            <option value="00"> Electives </option>
        </select> 
    </form>
    <div id='subject1div'>First results will display here</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><div id='subject2div'>Second results will display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: all your id's are the same - which is not permitted in html - change them to something unique, and use that in the onclick

Comment: Changed ids to subject1, subject2, etc but still not working.

Comment: Show your updated code

Comment: If you made the changes as I suggested, i.e. changed the ID's **and the text passed in the onclick**, grade will be correct, however, sender will now be subject1/subject2/subject3 etc - if that has to be subject1 in this case, use `document.getElementById(sender).value` for the subject parameter in the AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Here's the changes I'd make to your code

- In the onclick, pass `this` as the parameter
- In the `ajaxFunction` use `sender.name` and `sender.value` to get the subject and Year respectively
- Use `xhr.onload` rather than the antiquated `onreadystatechange` - but not sure which versions of IE support xhr2

So it ends up like this

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(sender){    
    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onload = function(){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById(sender.name + "div");
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
    // Now get the value from user and pass it to the server script.
    var queryString = "?grade=" + sender.value + "&subject=" + sender.name;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "process_ajax_7.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
</script>
    <form action="process.php" method="get" name="myform">
        <label><input type="radio" id = "subject1" name="subject1" onclick=ajaxFunction(this); value="09">Grade 9</label>
        <label><input type="radio" id = "subject2" name="subject1" onclick=ajaxFunction(this); value="10">Grade 10</label>
        <label><input type="radio" id = "subject3" name="subject1" onclick=ajaxFunction(this); value="11">Grade 11</label>
        <label><input type="radio" id = "subject4" name="subject1" onclick=ajaxFunction(this); value="12">Grade 12</label>
        <br><br>
        <select id="subject2" name="subject2" onchange=ajaxFunction('subject2');>
            <option> </option>
            <option value="09"> Year 9 </option>
            <option value="10"> Year 10 </option>
            <option value="11"> Year 11 </option>
            <option value="12"> Year 12 </option>
            <option value="00"> Electives </option>
        </select> 
    </form>
    <div id='subject1div'>First results will display here</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><div id='subject2div'>Second results will display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```